# Filter by time and date in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

I have a table of data which have date and time as two separate field where date format is

dd/mm/yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy and time format is like hh:mm:ss(eg: 6:52:53)

i need to filter the record for a particular time period that both time and date wise filtering.

is there any predefined filter available with hive or pig?

Answer (score 0):

Hive does recognize certain strings as unixtime dates.

You might try a where condition while concatenating the time & date together into unixtime format.

Some documentation on Hive date functions/formats are located here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have one column having two date format ie. dd/mm/yyyy and dd-mm-yyyy

What You can try
 1) Replacing '/' to '-' so that complete column will be in dd-mm-yyyy format.
 2) Try concatanating this field with time field 
 3) filter it by Casting concatinated field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `update cdr_data set TD =(select concat(concat(concat(concat(substr(date,7),"-"),concat(substr(date,4,2),"-")),concat(substr(date,1,2)," ")),time) from cdr_data)` 


As per your instruction i changed the the date format as per hive Timestamp using substring and concatenation operation , 

the select statement giving the desired time format but unable to update the values directly into the table is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

just possibility :- Have you tried casting that concatenated field to date datatype and then try date functions for desired output ?
eg. to_date()
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF